# My code runs but returns no output, I need assistance please?

Tags: python, output, cs50

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

def main():
    csv_path = argv[2]
    with open(csv_path) as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: you need to call `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

You never call the `main` function. To call it put `main()` at the end of your code. Then you final code will look like:

```py
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

def main():
    csv_path = argv[2]
    with open(csv_path) as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to call `main()` like this:

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

def main():
    csv_path = argv[2]
    with open(csv_path) as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```